# groovy rosserial does not recognize the location of the sketchbook

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04
groovy

I have installed the rosserial by using the instructions at
github.com/ros-drivers/roserial and followed the catkin instructions

cd catkin_ws
catkin make
catkin make install
source ~/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash
cd /home/charlie/sketchbook/libraries
rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py

everything seems to work OK up to this point, then I get the following statement

"make_libraries.py generates the Arduino rosserial library files. It requires the location of your Arduino sketchbook/libraries folder"

Arduino is installed on the desktop.

Any ideas ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70609/groovy-rosserial-does-not-recognize-the-location-of-the-sketchbook/) by [CharlieD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4148/charlied/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The command to make the libraries is `rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .`  The period is need to specify your current directory.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CharlieD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4148/charlied/) on 2013-08-04**:
That was it, it worked perfectly, Thanks for your help